Linux ls /FolderName "No such file or directory"
IDK but my ls command doesn't seems to recognize my Desktop items.
ls /bin ---> Shows bin content
ls /test ---> "No such file or directory", directory exists on Desktop

Are you sure that /bin is the folder on your Desktop, and isn't some other bin?

Use a relative path: ls test or ls Desktop/test.

Slash at the start of your path means you're looking at the root of your filesystem.

You probably want ls ~/Desktop/test -- ls test would only work if the Desktop were your current working directory.

thank you!!! " ls test "     WORKS !
